# radiogroup behavior on orientation change

Tags: android, radio-button, screen-orientation

I am hoping that someone can help me understand what's going on with respect to an Android radiogroup and the onCheckedChanged callbacks when the orientation changes.

I have a radio group with three radio buttons. The second button is defined as the default by setting the checked attribute to true. My xml for the radio group is as follows:

```
    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/rgReportRange"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/One" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="@string/Two" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Three" />
    </RadioGroup>
```

The RadioGroup has an onCheckedChangedListener. When the orientation changes, the onCheckedChangedListener is being called back differently based on which button is selected before the orientation change.

If button1 is selected, I see one callback to the onCheckedChanged method with checkedID equal to button1.

If button2 is selected, I see no callback to the onCheckedChanged method.

If button3 is selected, I see two callbacks to the onCheckedChanged method. The first callback has checkedID equal to button2. The second callback has checkedID equal to button3.

I don't understand the difference in behavior between the first and third cases. In both, there is a radio button other than the default selected.

Comment: This issue was also causing me problems. I found a solution to my specific situation and posted the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22438780/oncheckedchanged-being-called-on-device-rotate

Answer (score -1):

Make changes to the xml file like :

```
         <activity android:name=".YourActivityName"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.[How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score -2):

open your manifest.xml file and modify in Activity<> tag :

```
<activity
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"></activity>
```

after this check your result : :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This does avoid the issue. But I am still curious about why it was behaving the way it was.