# Check if onCheckedChanged called by user input and not device rotate

Tags: java, android

I am having the same issue as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10647001/radiogroup-behavior-on-orientation-change) unanswered question

**my question is:**

Is there a way to find out if the onCheckedChanged method is called by user input (*specifically the user selecting a radio button option*) or if it is being called due to device rotation?

Thanks,

Comment: No there is no way.  You probably are setting a listener in your code and that code is executing.

Comment: Well that is disheartening. I simply want the selection of a radio button to execute some code, however i do not want that same code to execute simply because the orientation changed...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

hallelujah!

**This Works!**:

```
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

    if (group.findViewById(checkedId).isPressed()) {
       //This will only execute if pressed. not if device rotates
    }

}
```

Comment: This fails if the user swipes the button instead of tapping on it

Comment: I assume because ```isPressed``` returns false? If you have a solution I can update the answer.